# What IP addresses are appropriate for a network inside an embedded device?

Tags: subnet, ip-address, networking, port-forwarding

I am making an embedded device with two processors, a "gateway" processor which is connected to external ethernet, and a "webServer" processor, which is only connected to the gateway via a second MAC on the gateway (MAC-to-MAC connection).

The key requirement is that this device should look like one device from the outside.  One IP address, etc.

So I set up the two on their own embedded subnet so they can talk to each other. Then I set up the gateway to port-forward packets on port 80 to the webServer so it can service them, and setup the webServer to use the gateway as, well, a gateway.  Thus, to the user, it looks like one device with one IP address regardless of whether they are using http or a different function serviced directly by the gateway.

This all works great, but I have been using IP address combinations that I know don't conflict.  That is to say, I know that I am not plugging my device into a subnet that overlaps with the embedded one.  In the real world, I don't have that luxury.  The end user can assign just about any IP address/subnet they want to the device (except multicast, broadcast, loopback etc.), and it is supposed to work.

So then I thought I'll just address hop the internal subnet.  I'll put it on 10.0.0.0/4 and if the user assigns a 10.X.X.X address I'll have them hop the internal addresses over to 176.16.0.0/4.  But then I thought, well, this device could be placed on a 10.X.X.X subnet, but could get accessed by a 176.16.X.X device through a gateway, which could still lead to address conflicts that wouldn't happen in a one-processor device.

So my question is, is there a standard practice for assigning IP addresses to an subnet inside an embedded device?  Do you normally address hop between private subnet ranges?  Or do you just pick a set of assigned public addresses and hope your users are sensible enough not to use them in their private network?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: Whatever you choose, it MUST be configurable, and *documented*. Just look at all the problems that surfaced with 1.1.1.1 when 1/8 was allocated. Even the mighty Cisco had *multiple* products with that embedded in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no standard practice for this kind of 'hidden' network.

A /31 subnet with two usable addresses is all you need. Likely, your best bet is to use an obscure subnet from the RFC 1918 address ranges (192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12, 10.0.0.0/8) that has little chance to be in use already (e.g. 10.196.188.88/31). Make sure you document your choice.

[EDIT]: I entirely forgot about ***link-local* addresses** that should be the right choice - they're not routable and only valid for a single L2 network. A /31 subnet from 169.254.0.0/16 (without 169.254.0.0/24 and 169.254.255.0/24) could be the answer.

Note that 176.16.0.0/4 is *not* a freely usable range, neither is 10.0.0.0/4 (thx Teun) - they're not even valid prefixes.

Comment: Neither is the bigger part of 10.0.0.0/4. Only 10.0.0.0/8 is available for private networks.

Comment: My question was closed as off topic, but thank you just the same.  It's a shame some small range hasn't been allocated for this given increasing complexity of IOT devices.  Sorry about the botched notation.  I was thinking 4 available addresses, then my brain shorted out and I wrote /4 instead of /30.

Comment: One should be thinking about, and *using*, IPv6. If you want to be 100% *absolutely certain* there will never be a collision, use your own registered address space. (I've seen cable operators do that.) Of course, if that block is ever reassigned, problems will ensue. This was, in theory, addressed with the top of ULA space [fc00::/8], but that space is still officially unused.

Comment: There's also 127/8. You'd have to "bend" a few rules, but inside an embedded device, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Ricky I considered that, too, but it would require some modifications on the IP stacks which I'm not sure the OP is able to do. After all, I'd do it all in a more integrated way - running internal M2M communication over Ethernet with two full stacks sounds very much like overkill.

Comment: @Zac67 *We* may think it's overkill. The MBA's and PHB's, just want fast and cheap. And since just about every lego block in the world has an ethernet port and IP stack...

Comment: (also, in linux, it's a one line change. or it used to be.)

Comment: @Ricky, Good ideas.  The application is only IPv4 though, and the only reason the SW port forwarding is fast enough is because we just change a few bytes and kick it out the other mac.  If the internal network was IPv6, I'd be chewing time reallocating buffers and memcpying.  I'm going to look into 127/8.  That might be viable depending on the stack changes needed.

Comment: (hint: change the definition of ipv4_is_loopback. I'd change it to match just 7f000001)